# Django: filter by a property defined on a model, in a DRY way?

Tags: python, django

I'm working in Django 1.10. I have a model like this:

```
class MyEvent(models.Model):
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    starts = models.DateTimeField()
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    def in_past(self):
        return self.starts.date() < datetime.date.today()

    def is_interesting(self):
        return self.url or not self.in_past()
```

In a couple of different places in my app, I want to show only events that are "interesting" as defined above, i.e. have a URL or aren't in the past. I want to display headers in the template if any such events exist.

I don't seem to be able to do this in my views:

```
events = MyEvent.objects.filter(is_interesting=False)
```

in the view. In the template, I can filter individual events by this property, but I can't tell if there are any such events:

```
{% if events.is_interesting.any %}Interesting events{% endif %}
```

always returns false.

Is there any way I can get a list of "interesting" events in my views or templates, in a DRY way?

Answer (score 2):

You are unable to filter like that because `is_interesting` isn't a model field. It's a function in your model, which can only be executed in the python side but cannot be executed in the DB side. You need to rewrite your query as follows.

```
events = MyEvent.objects.exclude(url=None).exclude(url='').filter(starts__lte=date.today())
```

note that you have defined your url as

```
url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Which forces you to check for both blank and null.

Once you got the query working you can create a custom queryset manager and and define a function that modifies the queryset to include those filters and keep things dry

If you want to do an OR condition you need [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q

events = MyEvent.objects.exclude(Q(Q(url=None) | Q(url='')) & Q((starts__lte=date.today())
```

I can't quite figure out the exact mix of OR and AND you want to use. Hope you will be able to figure it out using this guide line and the refferenced document. As already mentioned, using both null=True and blank=True makes your task that much harder.

Comment: The problem is that it's an OR query not an AND - interesting events are those which *either* have a URL, or start later than today. Is it possible to filter for those in a DRY way?

Comment: to keep things DRY you need to write your query inside a function that can be reused. Whether the query uses AND or OR is not related to the DRY principal

Answer (score 0):

You can define such methods on your custom managers and/or QuerySets:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods

Comment: A good answer would also include a quote from the linked article. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question Also writing a custom manager won't really solve his main issue which is the fact that "is_interesting" ain't a field